# Very simple events implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, event-handling, polymorphism

I've been thinking about implementing events and wrote some abstract code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Event>
class Dispatcher
{
public:
    class Listener
    {
    public:
        virtual void OnEvent(Event& event, Dispatcher& sender) {};
    };

private:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Listener> ListenerPtr;
    typedef std::vector<ListenerPtr> Listeners;
    Listeners _listeners;

public:
    void Reg(ListenerPtr listener)
    {
        if( _listeners.end() != std::find(_listeners.begin(), _listeners.end(), listener) )
            return;

        _listeners.push_back(listener);
    }

    void Unreg(ListenerPtr listener)
    {
        Listeners::iterator iter = std::find(_listeners.begin(), _listeners.end(), listener);
        if( _listeners.end() == iter )
            return;

        _listeners.erase(iter);
    }

    void Dispatch(Event& event)
    {
        for( Listeners::iterator iter = _listeners.begin(); iter != _listeners.end(); ++iter )
            (*iter)->OnEvent(event, *this);
    }
};

struct SomeEvent
{
    int someParam;
    SomeEvent(int someParam) : someParam(someParam) {}
};

class SomeDispatcher : public Dispatcher<SomeEvent>
{
};

struct OtherEvent
{
    int otherParam;
    OtherEvent(int otherParam) : otherParam(otherParam) {}
};

class OtherDispatcher :
    public SomeDispatcher, public Dispatcher<OtherEvent>
{
};

class Consumer :
    public Dispatcher<SomeEvent>::Listener,
    public Dispatcher<OtherEvent>::Listener
{
    virtual void OnEvent(SomeEvent& event, Dispatcher<SomeEvent>& sender)
    {
        std::cout << "OnEvent SomeEvent " << event.someParam << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void OnEvent(OtherEvent& event, Dispatcher<OtherEvent>& sender)
    {
        std::cout << "OnEvent OtherEvent " << event.otherParam << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    OtherDispatcher dispatcher;

    std::shared_ptr<Consumer> consumer(new Consumer());

    dispatcher.Dispatcher<SomeEvent>::Reg( consumer );
    dispatcher.Dispatcher<OtherEvent>::Reg( consumer );

    dispatcher.Dispatcher<SomeEvent>::Dispatch(SomeEvent(1));
    dispatcher.Dispatcher<OtherEvent>::Dispatch(OtherEvent(2));

    dispatcher.Dispatcher<SomeEvent>::Unreg( consumer );

    dispatcher.Dispatcher<SomeEvent>::Dispatch(SomeEvent(3));
    dispatcher.Dispatcher<OtherEvent>::Dispatch(OtherEvent(4));

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and works as expected, but... I have to write more code to inherit from `Dispatcher` and `Listener`, to register listener and to define more exactly which dispatcher I'm registering to. And this method does not allow registering of custom class method, but only `OnEvent()`.

Apart from this, are there any issues with this code? Is it compatible with different compilers and platforms? Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you make Listener::OnEvent(...) into a pure virtual destructor, turning Listener into an interface? That would clear up most of your inheritance issues.

Comment: @ShotgunNinja What do you mean by "inheritance issues"?

Answer (score 6):

Listner needs a virtual destructor
and the `OnEvent()` method should probably be pure virtual:

```
class Listener
{
public:
    virtual void OnEvent(Event& event, Dispatcher& sender) {};
};

// Try

class Listener
{
    public:
        virtual ~Listener() {}
        virtual void OnEvent(Event& event, Dispatcher& sender) = 0;
};
```

You need the virtual destructor because delete will more than likely be called via a pointer to the base class (Listener) at some point.

No point in implementing `OnEvent()` to do nothing if you need sombody to over-ride it.

Personally I would prefer to use `boost::ptr_vector<>` rather than a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<>>`. The boost vector has a couple of advantages (less lcoks required). Also its members are provided via references rather than pointers so it makes it more natural to use with the standard algorithms (not such a big deal in C++11 (with lambdas) but it makes C++03 much easier to use).

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Listener> ListenerPtr;
typedef std::vector<ListenerPtr> Listeners;
Listeners _listeners;

// Replace with:

boost::ptr_vector<Listener>  listeners;
```

Be careful of using '_` on the front of identifiers. The rules are not obvious so best avoided to make sure you don't actually break them. [Underscore Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797)

Personally not a fan of the following:

```
   if( _listeners.end() != std::find(_listeners.begin(), _listeners.end(), listener) )
```

Nothing wrong with it. But reversing the order of the test just makes you pause a second. See [Yoda Conditionals](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/162256/12917).

Prefer to use standard algorithms rather than hand coded loops.

```
   for( Listeners::iterator iter = _listeners.begin(); iter != _listeners.end(); ++iter )
        (*iter)->OnEvent(event, *this);

   // Try
   std::for_each(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(),
                 std::bind2nd(Listner::OnEvent, event)
                ); // Assume boost::ptr_vector<>

   // Or go all C++11 on us
   std::for_each(std::begin(listeners), std::end(listeners),
                 [&event](std::shared_ptr<Listener>& lis) {lis->OnEvent(event);}
                );
```

If you want to have listeners that only deal with a specific type of event. You can write your Listner to be a filtering lsitener.

```
class Listener
{
public:
    virtual void OnEvent(Event& event, Dispatcher& sender) {};
};
```

Change to:

```
template<class ForEvent>
class Listener
{
    public:
        ~Listener() {}

        // This is the method called by the dispatcher.
        void eventFilter(OnEvent& event, Dispatcher& sender)
        {
             // dynamic_cast to a pointer type.
             // Result is NULL if not the correct type.
             // If you used a value type then it would throw an exception.
             ForEvent* specialEvent = dynamic_cast<ForEvent*>(&event);
             if (specialEvent != NULL)
             {
                 // Only call the OnEvent for the types we want.
                 // put back to a references (so OnEvent does not need to
                 // check for NULL).
                 this->OnEvent(*specialEvent, sender);
             }
        }

        virtual void OnEvent(ForEvent& event, Dispatcher& sender) = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::find` is in header `<algorithm>`, which is missing.

For me it did not compile without it.

Answer (score -1):

So, I think the following scenario will break the otherwise elegant Dispatcher class:

The consumer removes itself from the Dispatcher within the OnEvent() notification.

Suppose the example were a single shot timer expiration and the consumer wants to remove itself from notifications once the timer it is interested in expires.